# Custom Page Order instead of Alphabetical

Tags: pages

I'm going to try to word this the best that I can.  I apologize if it gets confusing.  Anyway, I am creating pages for my website and when I go to create the pages, I want them to appear in a certain order on the website:

Home
About
Services
Photographs
Logos
Contact

However, every time I create the pages, they list in alphabetical order instead of how I would like.  Does anyone know how I am able to fix this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom navigation menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) and order the pages in `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`. You shouldn’t mess around with `wp_list_pages()` anymore.

To get a *Home* link into the list of available pages add the following code to your theme’s `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'add_home_link_to_nav_menu_editor' );
function add_home_link_to_nav_menu_editor( $args )
{
    $args['show_home'] = TRUE;
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Page Attributes" meta box in the page editor that contains a Page Order option. Enter a number.

Or, if your theme supports WP3 menus, go to Appearance>>Menus and drag and drop and save your pages into a different order.

Answer (score 0):

page attributes is correct, but i find it extremely un-intuitive.  most themes don't support it out of the box, but happily there is a plugin that does handles drap and drop page ordering:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-page-order/